# Why NSDecimalNumber(string:"2175613.285964774433431797660").intValue = 0 , who can help me

Tags: ios, swift, foundation, nsdecimalnumber

[image]

Why `NSDecimalNumber(string:"2175613.285964774433431797660").intValue` = 0

`NSDecimalNumber(string:"2175613.285964774433431797660").int32Value` = 2175613

`NSDecimalNumber(string:"2175613.285964774433431797660").int64Value` = 0

Who can help me?

Apple M1
Mac OS Ventura 13.0
Xcode 14.1

```
let a = NSDecimalNumber(string: "2175613.285964774433431797660188672").intValue
// a == 0 is true
```

This problem caused our users' wallet balances to clear directly to zero.

Comment: Can you tell us what’s the purpose of all those fractional digits? Btw you are supposed to use Swift native types, in this case `Decimal`

Comment: I see the same issue on an Intel Mac with macOS 13.4 using a Swift Playground in Xcode 14.3.

Comment: Right.  The documentation even states this specifically.  It is only useful for numbers with less than 38 significant digits.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber  If your users have balances with more than 38 significant digits, then you've done your math wrong.

Comment: @TimRoberts OP value has 26 significant digits and exponent -19

Comment: Instead of asking why this happens maybe you should ask yourself why you have ended up with a string with so many decimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like whenever the decimal significand overflows 64-bit Integer the result is unpredictable regardless of the decimal exponent value. One option to solve your issue is to round your decimal number before converting it to integer. You can overcome this issue as follow:

---

```
extension Decimal {
    func rounded(_ roundingMode: NSDecimalNumber.RoundingMode = .plain) -> Decimal {
        var result = Decimal()
        var number = self
        NSDecimalRound(&result, &number, 0, roundingMode)
        return result
    }

    var whole: Decimal { rounded(sign == .minus ? .up : .down) }
    var fraction: Decimal { self - whole }
}
```

---

```
extension Decimal {
    var number: NSDecimalNumber { self as NSDecimalNumber }

    var int: Int? {
        let whole = self.whole
        guard whole > Decimal(Int.min) && whole <= Decimal(Int.max) else { return nil }
        return whole.number.intValue
    }

    var int32: Int32? {
        let whole = self.whole
        guard whole > Decimal(Int32.min) && whole <= Decimal(Int32.max) else { return nil }
        return whole.number.int32Value
    }

    var int64: Int64? {
        let whole = self.whole
        guard whole > Decimal(Int64.min) && whole <= Decimal(Int64.max) else { return nil }
        return whole.number.int64Value
    }
}
```

---

---

```
let decimal1 = Decimal(string: "9223372036854775807")!
decimal1.int    // 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
decimal1.int32  // nil overflows Int32.max
decimal1.int64  // 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

---

```
let decimal2 = Decimal(string: "9223372036854775808")! // overflows Int.max
decimal2.significand        //  9,223,372,036,854,775,808 overflows Int.max
decimal2.number.intValue    // -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 undefined behavior
decimal2.number.int64Value  // -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 undefined behavior
decimal2.int    // nil
decimal2.int32  // nil
decimal2.int64  // nil
```

---

```
let decimal3 = Decimal(string: "2175613.9223372036854775807")! // overflows Int.max
String(describing: decimal3.significand).count // 26
decimal3.exponent           // -19
decimal3.significand        //  21,756,139,223,372,036,854,775,807 overflows Int.max
decimal3.number.intValue    // 0 undefined behavior
decimal3.number.int64Value  // 0 undefined behavior
decimal3.int    // 2,175,613
decimal3.int32  // 2,175,613
decimal3.int64  // 2,175,613
```

Comment: *** decimal3.number.int32Value       // 2,175,613  
decimal3.number.int64Value       // 0 *** 
Why?

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/733740 ,This is Apple Foundation Bug.